# How to change Font-family of Material icons angular 7 using CSS

Tags: css, material-design, angular7, font-family, google-material-icons

I'm using * {font-family: 'Arial' !important}. It changes font of material elements. but material-icons are not compatible with it. Example instead of icon it is showing "account_circle" which is code for icon.

Comment: Why are you using `!important` for a `*` selector?? This is the worst thing ever and it doesn't make sense, and also probably explain the issue

Comment: without ! important it's not working.

Comment: Here's a list of the supported browsers https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/supported-browsers.md - Which version of i.e are you using?